# Transparent checkmark in checkBox in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, android-jetpack-compose

In my Compose app I need to create a circle checkboxes. I've already achieved that with the code below:

```
@Composable
fun CircleCheckBox(
    isChecked: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onChecked: () -> Unit = {},
    checkedBackgroundColor: Color,
    unCheckedBackgroundColor: Color,
    checkedIconColor: Color,
    unCheckedIconColor: Color
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .clickable { onChecked() }
            .border(
                width = if (!isChecked) 1.dp else 0.dp,
                color = if (!isChecked) checkedBackgroundColor else Color.Transparent,
                shape = CircleShape
            )
            .background(
                color = if (isChecked) checkedBackgroundColor else unCheckedBackgroundColor,
                shape = CircleShape
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.icon_check),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp),
            tint = if (isChecked) checkedIconColor else unCheckedIconColor
        )
    }
}
```

But in my app I have a gradient backgrounds on cards, so I want to make checkmarks transparent, but in this realization it's impossible because of the background of the Box. Is there any way to achieve it, like on image below?

[image: Checkboxes example]

[image: Checkboxes example 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an appropriate default icons instead of drawing on your own. `Icons.Default.CheckCircle` is what you're looking for - it has transparent checkmark inside a filled circle. And you can use `Icons.Outlined.Circle` instead of border modifier:

```
@Composable
fun CircleCheckBox(
    isChecked: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onChecked: () -> Unit = {},
    color: Color,
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .clickable { onChecked() }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = if (isChecked) Icons.Default.CheckCircle else Icons.Outlined.Circle,
            contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.icon_check),
            tint = color
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by importing custom icon vector like this

[image]

Here, the check is transparent so, it will show the gradient background.