# How do I set border color for the checkbox using jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-checkbox

I need to implement checkbox that looks like this

[image]

I have tried to explore all the aspects provided by compose to alter the checkbox as below

```
colors: CheckboxColors = CheckboxDefaults.colors()
```

I found some alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548904/transparent-checkmark-in-checkbox-in-jetpack-compose) but

1. It doesn't works for me
2. I feel just to change the checkbox border color there shouldn't be so much work around right.

**Note**: checkmark color can be changed by using color field

```
colors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(checkmarkColor = Black)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't works for me"?

Comment: You can create your own implementation of `CheckboxColors`, but I don't see much case in doing so

Comment: @PylypDukhov

It doesn't shows checkbox at all for some reason. I did not invest much time on solving it as I feel there should be a right way of changing the border colors instead of workarounds. By looking more into checkboxDefaults.colors I see there is a something bordercolor but I don't know how will that work

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing using a Checkbox, and I don't think it's possible.  The design for checkbox in Jetpack is a completely filled background.  So the border and background use the same color.  There is a field called "checkedBorderColor", but it is privately set and inaccessible.

Answer (score 4):

There is default colors function CheckboxDefaults.colors().
You can change the specific color.

```
@Composable
fun myCheckBoxColors(): CheckboxColors {
    return CheckboxDefaults.colors(
        checkedColor = Color.red,
        uncheckedColor = Color.transparent
    )
}
```

Comment: This won't let you set the border color, which is what the question was regarding.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `CheckboxColors` interface and create your color scheme.
I just copied the implementation of `DefaultCheckboxColors`:

```
@Stable
class YourCheckboxColors(
    private val checkedCheckmarkColor: Color,
    private val uncheckedCheckmarkColor: Color,
    private val checkedBoxColor: Color,
    private val uncheckedBoxColor: Color,
    private val disabledCheckedBoxColor: Color,
    private val disabledUncheckedBoxColor: Color,
    private val disabledIndeterminateBoxColor: Color,
    private val checkedBorderColor: Color,
    private val uncheckedBorderColor: Color,
    private val disabledBorderColor: Color,
    private val disabledIndeterminateBorderColor: Color
) : CheckboxColors {

    private val BoxInDuration = 50
    private val BoxOutDuration = 100
    private val CheckAnimationDuration = 100

    private val CheckboxRippleRadius = 24.dp
    private val CheckboxDefaultPadding = 2.dp
    private val CheckboxSize = 20.dp
    private val StrokeWidth = 2.dp
    private val RadiusSize = 2.dp

    @Composable
    override fun checkmarkColor(state: ToggleableState): State<Color> {
        val target = if (state == ToggleableState.Off) {
            uncheckedCheckmarkColor
        } else {
            checkedCheckmarkColor
        }

        val duration = if (state == ToggleableState.Off) BoxOutDuration else BoxInDuration
        return animateColorAsState(target, tween(durationMillis = duration))
    }

    @Composable
    override fun boxColor(enabled: Boolean, state: ToggleableState): State<Color> {
        val target = if (enabled) {
            when (state) {
                ToggleableState.On, ToggleableState.Indeterminate -> checkedBoxColor
                ToggleableState.Off -> uncheckedBoxColor
            }
        } else {
            when (state) {
                ToggleableState.On -> disabledCheckedBoxColor
                ToggleableState.Indeterminate -> disabledIndeterminateBoxColor
                ToggleableState.Off -> disabledUncheckedBoxColor
            }
        }

        // If not enabled 'snap' to the disabled state, as there should be no animations between
        // enabled / disabled.
        return if (enabled) {
            val duration = if (state == ToggleableState.Off) BoxOutDuration else BoxInDuration
            animateColorAsState(target, tween(durationMillis = duration))
        } else {
            rememberUpdatedState(target)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    override fun borderColor(enabled: Boolean, state: ToggleableState): State<Color> {
        val target = if (enabled) {
            when (state) {
                ToggleableState.On, ToggleableState.Indeterminate -> checkedBorderColor
                ToggleableState.Off -> uncheckedBorderColor
            }
        } else {
            when (state) {
                ToggleableState.Indeterminate -> disabledIndeterminateBorderColor
                ToggleableState.On, ToggleableState.Off -> disabledBorderColor
            }
        }

        // If not enabled 'snap' to the disabled state, as there should be no animations between
        // enabled / disabled.
        return if (enabled) {
            val duration = if (state == ToggleableState.Off) BoxOutDuration else BoxInDuration
            animateColorAsState(target, tween(durationMillis = duration))
        } else {
            rememberUpdatedState(target)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can set the colors by simply:

```
        Checkbox(
            colors = YourCheckboxColors(
                checkedBorderColor = Ink900,
                checkedBoxColor = Light,
                checkedCheckmarkColor = Ink900,
                uncheckedCheckmarkColor = Ink900.copy(alpha = 0f),
                uncheckedBoxColor = Light.copy(alpha = 0f),
                disabledCheckedBoxColor = Light,
                disabledUncheckedBoxColor = Light.copy(alpha = 0f),
                disabledIndeterminateBoxColor = Light,
                uncheckedBorderColor = Ink900,
                disabledBorderColor = Ink900,
                disabledIndeterminateBorderColor = Ink900,
            ),
            onCheckedChange = {}
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Checkbox(checked = checked == true,
         onCheckedChange = { scope.launch { setValue(key, it) } },
         colors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(uncheckedColor = Color.Gray))
```

In my case I than have only a gray border if the checkbox is unchecked. Maybe it also works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code and customize the checkbox border using Box.

```
@Composable
fun CustomCheckBox(
checked: Boolean,
onCheckedChange: ((Boolean) -> Unit),
checkBoxSize: Dp = 60.dp,
checkBoxBorderWidth: Dp = 1.dp,
checkBoxBorderColorSelected: Int = R.color.black,
checkBoxBorderColorUnSelected: Int = R.color.teal_200,
checkBoxCheckedIconColor: Int = R.color.black,
) {
// state is used to hold the checkbox click or not by default is false
val checkBoxState = remember { mutableStateOf(checked) }
// Ui for checkbox
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(BorderStroke(checkBoxBorderWidth,
            if (checkBoxState.value) colorResource(id = checkBoxBorderColorSelected)
            else colorResource(id = checkBoxBorderColorUnSelected)))
        .size(checkBoxSize)
        .background(Color.Transparent)
        .clickable {
            onCheckedChange(!checkBoxState.value)
            checkBoxState.value = !checkBoxState.value
        },
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    if (checkBoxState.value)
        Icon(Icons.Default.Check,
            tint = colorResource(id = checkBoxCheckedIconColor),
            contentDescription = "Custom CheckBox")
}
}
```